# php regex preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, regex

I have some inherited code whose purpose is to identify urls in a string an prepend the http:// protocol onto them if it doesn't exist.

```
return preg_replace_callback(
        '/((https?:\/\/)?\w+(\.\w{2,})+[\w?&%=+\/]+)/i',
        function ($match) {
            if (stripos($match[1], 'http://') !== 0 && stripos($match[1], 'https://') !== 0) {
                $match[1] = 'http://' . $match[1];
            }
            return $match[1];
        },
        $string);
```

It's working, except when a domain has a hyphen it. So, for-instance, the following string will only partially work.

```
$string = "In front mfever.com/1 middle http://mf-ever.com/2 at the end";
```

Can any regex genius see what's wrong with it?

Comment: `\w` only matches letter, digits and `_`. You will need to use a character class with allowed chars. Say, `[\w-]` to also match hyphens.

Comment: If any of the provided solutions worked, please be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the optional dash:

```
((https?:\/\/)?\w+\-?\w+(\.\w{2,})+[\w?&%=+\/]+)
```

See it work here https://regex101.com/r/Tkdapj/1

Comment: your regex will break if more than 1 hyphens are present.